# Integrating Angular 6 written using typescript with existing GWT framework

Tags: javascript, typescript, gwt, angular6, smartgwt

There is an assignment to create an app in angular 6 and integrate with existing codebase written in GWT. I have created the app using angular 6 in typescript but not sure how to integrate the generated sources (DIST/package name) with GWT. Any help shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "integrate"?

Comment: The overall UI application is developed using GWT, and some new apps needs to be developed in Angular 6. Those apps needs to be integrated to fit into the GWT structure.